# MySQL 5.5 : Cannot drop database : Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, innodb

After a huge crash of my mysql database, I've made a recovery, all is ok except one schema.
In phpMyAdmin, this schema doest not cotains any tables, but we i ask mysql to drop the schema (drop database xxxx) I've the following error :

```
Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

In the mysql error.log, I see the following :

```
InnoDB: Load table 'xxxx/menu' failed, the table has missing foreign key indexes. Turn off 'foreign_key_checks' and try again.140120 10:52:35  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139903484229376 in file row0mysql.c line 3822
InnoDB: Failing assertion: table
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
09:52:35 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
bugs at http://bugs.percona.com/

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=6
max_threads=153
thread_count=5
connection_count=5
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 351196 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x314ff30
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7f3dd17aee80 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x7c613e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0x69daf4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0)[0x7f3dd0d96cb0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x7f3dcff87425]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x17b)[0x7f3dcff8ab8b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x813038]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7eb25c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x69db6f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24plugin_foreach_with_maskP3THDPFcS0_P13st_plugin_intPvEijS3_+0x226)[0x5b2376]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_rm_dbP3THDPcbb+0x616)[0x587ca6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x139e)[0x5a411e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x314)[0x5aa304]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x20a4)[0x5ac454]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x137)[0x648397]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x51)[0x648471]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7e9a)[0x7f3dd0d8ee9a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f3dd00453fd]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f3d98004b60): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 710
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

I have tested all innodb_force_recovery value (1 to 6) and disable foreing key checks, but nothings help...
Moreover, in the information_schema I can see some values :

- In INNODB_SYS_TABLES
  ==> (1717, 'xxxx', 'menu', 1, 10, 0),
- In INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN ==> ('xxxx/menu_FK_1', 'xxxx/menu', 'kms_site1/page_zone_component', 1, 5),
- In INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS ==> ('xxxx/menu_FK_1', 'page_zone_component_id', 'id', 0),

I think, I've some residual table/index in innodb description file, but I don't know how to repair that...